# Present indefinite tense in past and future events

Tags: grammar, tenses

I heard it in a TV series "she hears everything i said"
And in a song lyrics "Whatever happens in the future, trust in destiny" 
Why they use present indefinite in these contexts?

Comment: Song lyrics and poetry don't always follow the rules, though the line you quoted sounds perfectly fine to me. The line from the TV show doesn't sound right though.

Comment: First, _trust_ is an imperative - not simply a present indefinitive. Second, the TV sentence can be perfectly correct if she (generally/regularly) hears things I said before e.g. from a recording, from a mutual friend.

Comment: From what I remember, and that aligns with your examples, the present tense is often used to describe things that have a long duration. So, she _always_ hears everything (she did, and presumably always will, too), and the future is intended to bound on eternity, so whatever _happens_ gets a notion of "now or later".